# Turn-by-Turn Navigation for our driver app

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, maps

I am currently in charge of developing an iOS delivery driver app for our company. What are some available (preferably Free) Turn-by-Turn SDK's or tools. We don't have many drivers so it would be limited usage of the service. I have done some research on Google Maps iOS SDK and have spoken to them as well over the phone. They do Not offer their Turn-by-Turn capabilities within a third party app.

Thanks

Comment: iOS has buit in tools for turn-by-turn directions with iOS 7 and up using MapKit's MKDirections API

Answer (score 1):

You can a solution based on OpenStreetMap, like the [Scout SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/), that allows you to embed turn by turn directly inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

For android: There are no turn-by-turn SDK's/tools currently available that you can use within a third party app. Your options are to build your own, or launch an app like Google Maps or Waze with parameters like start/end locations.

Comment: Based on the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-using-google it seems like you should be able to use Google Maps & Directions API

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.mapbox.com/ both for iOS & Android.

Comment: Tool requests are off-topic on SO for a while but if you answer those make sure to include context on how to use/ apply the tool or SDK. Just a link is barely an answer.