# Turn-By-Turn navigation using Google Map SDK and Swift in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

There is an app, that should provide turn by turn navigation. At the moment it uses Google Map SDK and I was able to draw a route using Google Directions API and GMSPath using tutorial from [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/). Problem is it looks kind of ugly - simply thin blue line.

My questions is it possible create turn by turn navigation inside an app using Google Maps?

Comment: According to their policy you are not allowed to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231295/1395437

Comment: @DanielZolnai So what's the point of having Directions feature? To show user a possible route to destination, but then not provide the navigation to the destination?

Comment: You can show the directions as a list. But turn-by-turn navigation would make a competing app.

Comment: @DanielZolnai so if an app does not provide directions, but simply updates the route to the destination, would that be allowed?

Comment: No, that falls under "real time navigation or route guidance". You can show it to the user, but can not update it in real time.

Comment: @DanielZolnai little bit offtopic, but maybe you are aware if MapKit allows that?

Comment: Yes you can, see their documentations: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html

Answer (score 1):

I think Google does provide this option but not for free.

Have a look at this:
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/ridesharing/