# Can we Hide Google Maps Splash Screen while Starting an Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

In my application, I place button to navigate the user to one particular location. When user clicks the navigate button, this code will get executed and opens the Google Maps application to show the turn by turn navigation.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+"11.545526,60.245177");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Is it possible to hide the splash screen of Google Maps or show other image over it? I need them to show the navigation map directly without showing the Google Maps splash screen.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have to say "No".
No, We simply can't.

Comment: Correct me If i'm wrong. While I'm travelling in Uber, driver clicks the navigation button in his app and it started navigation by showing a blank white screen for few seconds. How is it actually working?

Comment: @Mann, What about com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView ?

Comment: @Uday, It is because they possibly have been implemented their own activity/module just like the google maps app.

Comment: @whoami, Using mapview in your app is not hiding the classing google maps splashscreen. However, I suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` to include the map in your app. We used it in one our app to plot the user search results on the map.

Check the example in https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

Comment: Is it possible to show turn by turn navigation using MapView?

Comment: @Uday, MapView is an answer for your question to hide Google Maps Splash screen. For your 2nd question about navigation, I don't know whether its possible or not but we shouldn't do as per the Google T&C. Plz check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231295/710817