# Improve GPS accuracy - Android turn-by-turn map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am building a navigation application similar to waze.
I have a problem in the accuracy of GPS positions. When I'm driving the car on the street, my marker position is on the sidewalk and sometimes across the street.
I would like to have a similar precision to the waze and googlemaps where the position is always on the street.
I'm already leaving the Accuracy fine but did not work.

Comment: Might want to look at this, it sounds like what you're trying to do goes against the terms of use : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231295/4409409

Comment: For some additional information, a turn by turn navigation is prohibited in Google Maps API but simple routing is ok. You can check this [tutorial](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary) and its [documentation](http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you must tell the app that there is a road/path, and then snap your location to this road or path.

you can use the snap to road api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

> You can make requests to the snapToRoads method of the Google Maps
>   Roads API at the following URL. All requests must be sent via HTTPS.
>
> https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?parameters&key=YOUR_API_KEY
>   Parameter Usage
>
> Required Parameters
>
> path — The path to be snapped. The path parameter accepts a list of
>   latitude/longitude pairs. Latitude and longitude values should be
>   separated by commas. Coordinates should be separated by the pipe
>   character: "|". For example:
>   path=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796.