# How to integrate google map navigation in iOS to our app?

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to integrate google map navigation for Turn-By-Turn direction. In My app

Thanks

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-using-google/36079071#36079071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Terms of Service this is not allowed. Look at paragraph 10.4 (c) of ToS:

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions