# It is possible to create turn-by-turn navigation in google map API's?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, navigation, gps

I am developing my ***ionic application for android***. I have implemented google map in my application using Google Maps API and the Google Directions API.

Everything is possible by using ***Google Map API for Android***.

But, I can not find any useful information about ***Turn-by-turn navigation implementation*** inside my app.

***Can someone help me - is it possible to use Google Maps inside an Android app to create turn-by-turn GPS based app?***

Anyone help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create turn-by-turn GPS navigation app on Android using Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-using-google)

Comment: Suggestion given there to use other maps. I need to implement it in google map

Comment: @Priya you don't read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231295/3629732

Comment: Yeah!!! I have referred that already. That question was raised on 2014 I think...For any new updates is available to solve this problem??

Comment: @Priya No. Note : The [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231295/3629732) edited jul 19

Comment: ok..Thanks for your response..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128612/discussion-between-rajesh-rajendiran-and-s-m-priya).