# Swift Google Maps SDK, navigation inside my app

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

It's possible with Google Maps's SDK to start a navigation with directions from point A to point B?

For having something like this:[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create turn-by-turn GPS navigation app on Android/iOS using Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-ios-using-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can show routes on google map using Goole Map platform APIS.

But you can't implement same way like in google map(with voice). You can use Direction API by google to get the path points from Point A to Point B and draw a polyline on google map.

Google does not provide navigation with voice as in google map. There is no such apis available from google.

For more details about this visit [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start)

Comment: Many thanks, I see and it's impossibile with the Google's SDK I try with another tool