# Get Route Navigation in App using Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

Is there a way to get navigation directions like we get in google maps using google maps API?
I know how to get route (directions API) and then display it (Maps JavaScript API) but i can't find a way to get navigation directions for that route. I need the map to navigate the user to the destination.

Comment: Via text (available, see the docs)? Or voice (not available)?

Comment: i need voice navigation.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to create turn-by-turn GPS navigation app on Android/iOS using Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531391/is-it-possible-to-create-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-app-on-android-ios-using-go)

I found this already answered question which answers my question too.